# where is my error in this area, can you edit the code?

Tags: mysql

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lang;
CREATE TABLE lang (
   ID int( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   key varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   value text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   KEY key (key)
);
```

MySQL said:

> Documentation #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
> manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
> syntax to use near 'varchar(255) NOT NULL, code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
> value text NOT NULL, ' at line 3

Answer (score 4):

key is a reserved word in mysql it must be escaped:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS lang;
CREATE TABLE lang (
   ID int( 11 ) NOT NULL auto_increment,
   `key` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
   code varchar(8) NOT NULL,
   value text NOT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (ID),
   KEY `key` (`key`)
);
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/3b6cd5